# When I bake a Rigid Body sim. , no keyframes appear

Tags: animation

I'm making a rigid body simulation of 150 separate pieces dropping onto a plane, lasting 250 frames.

It doesn't seem to matter what simulation I do. Even with just a single cube dropping, when I bake it, I get no keyframes, just a red line.

[image]

All I can see is a red line after I baked my animation. No matter which setting I adjust it is always the same. Adding a keyframe doesn't show either.

Comment: Hello, what kind of animation are you doing? Maybe share your file:https: //blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It's a rigid body simulation of 150 separate pieces dropping onto a plane, lasting 250 frames.
It doesn't seem to matter what simulation I do. Just a single cube dropping and when I bake it, I get no keyframes, just a red line.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake. I didn't realise that you had to bake the animation twice. First in the scene settings and then under Object - Rigid Body - Bake to Keyframes.

Comment: You don't have to bake it twice - you can bake it to keyframes if you want a fixed animation. Your fundamental mistake here is, you are doing a **simulation**, baking it will pre-calculate the simulation and store the data for faster playback (and evenutally avoid issues upon rendering later). You do not get any keyframes there because a simulation is not a keyframed animation. If you however bake it to keyframes, then the rigid bodies are no longer simulated and you cannot simply change the simulation by changing the inital settings. The animation is now fixed by keyframes.